# When loading a form, how do I retrieve the data passed by the "parent" form?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

This is the line which passes the argument to the "child" form:

> DoCmd.OpenForm "Main", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, tr.GetEmployeeName(uname)

Then this is the code for when the "child" form loads:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim i As String
i = CStr(Login.OpenArgs)
MsgBox i

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is already passed as a string, and is a property of the "child" form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()  
    Dim i As String 
    i = Me.OpenArgs 
    MsgBox i  
End Sub
```

EDIT: I almost missed this - it's been a while . . .

More editing: It looks like you are treating the OpenArgs as a property of the Parent form. I shall assume your Parent form is "login", and your child form is "Main", since you appear to be invoking a Form named "Main" in that line of code.

The openArgs is a property of the form now opening, passed to the child from the parent. Therefore, you reference the OpenArgs property as shown above.

Unless I am missing something, anyway . . .

Comment: Ooops. Forgot. If you want to reference the "child" form explicitly from within itself, instead of using the Me keyword, you need to use the full class name: